# Android: Unable to instantiate MediaCodec due to IllegalArgumentException on configure

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am learning how to work with `MediaCodec` so i am making an experiment to understand how it works, right now i am trying to create a codec which will receive data from the device's camera and transcode the footage to different resolution/bitrate.

I am trying to set up a `MediaCodec` instance with a `Surface`, but i fail to have it configured. These are the errors i see in the `Logcat` when i hit the configure code line:

```
2020-01-03 11:22:01.769 25735-25735/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.kirin.product.platform"
2020-01-03 11:22:01.769 25735-25735/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/HwExtendedCodec: mime: video/avc matching compontent failed!
2020-01-03 11:22:01.782 25735-25918/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/ACodec: [OMX.hisi.video.encoder.avc] failed to set output port definition parameters.
2020-01-03 11:22:01.782 25735-25918/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/ACodec: [OMX.hisi.video.encoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -22
2020-01-03 11:22:01.782 25735-25918/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -22)
2020-01-03 11:22:01.782 25735-25917/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffea, actionCode 0, while in state 3
2020-01-03 11:22:01.785 25735-25735/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xffffffea, resetting...
2020-01-03 11:22:01.802 25735-25735/com.oscar.vtech.multistreamtest E/MainActivity: Unable to start recording: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

The code that instantiates the `MediaCodec` and configures it is like this:

```
public class VideoEncoder {
    private static final String TAG = VideoEncoder.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE = MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC;                             // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static final int DEFAULT_COLOR_FORMAT = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FRAME_RATE = 30;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FRAME_INTERVAL = 3;

    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private Surface inputSurface;

    public VideoEncoder(int width, int height, int bitrate) throws IOException {
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE, width, height);

        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, DEFAULT_COLOR_FORMAT);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, DEFAULT_FRAME_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, DEFAULT_FRAME_INTERVAL);

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("mediaFormat: %s", mediaFormat));

        this.mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE);

        this.mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

        this.inputSurface = this.mediaCodec.createInputSurface();

        this.mediaCodec.start();
    }

    public Surface getInputSurface() {
        return inputSurface;
    }
}
```

This is the debug log of the `mediaFormat` values that are set:

```
color-format=19, i-frame-interval=3, mime=video/avc, width=842, bitrate=2000, frame-rate=30, height=480
```

If there's any place i can learn more about how to work with codecs so i could understand how to properly work with `MediaCodec`, please share and i will really appreciate it.

Comment: You may have a lot more luck trying `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` and using a higher bitrate, maybe try something around `100000` for starters, until you can get it working. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo) for some docs you'll need to read.

Comment: @greeble31 I have tried on trying different color formats like `COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible` and using different bitrates like `2000 * 1000`, but still the codec fails to configure, it either fails on configure or creating the surface.

Comment: Should i worry about this error message? `E/HwExtendedCodec: mime: video/avc matching compontent failed!`

Comment: Yes, you should. That probably corresponds to an invalid configuration. But then again, so does the presence of an `IllegalStateException`. Now, you can try whichever `COLOR_Formats` you please, but if they're not represented in the `MediaCodecInfo`, don't expect the function to succeed.

Comment: Hi, could you launch this test ? https://gist.github.com/aelqsimi/f773d63fd5f234df7892276e3b05e5f8 or use MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities to show your device capabilities ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities

Comment: @E.Abdel your gist file had unknown references so i had to tweak it a bit in order to run.. I have found that the codec i am trying to use is compatible and it supports the color format i am trying to configure.. it at least shows that but i am still struggling to set this up

Comment: Can you tell me please what is your device and Android version?

Comment: @E.Abdel Sorry for the late response, the device in which i am running the tests are done on an Huawei Honor 20 with Android 9

Comment: Hi @Reyes, I investigated for a moment to understand what happening but I can't figured it out, can you try again by setting the max height, max width and max input size for your encoder (width * height) using the setInteger method : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html#setInteger(java.lang.String,%20int) ? Also, avoid to use sizes that are not a multiple of 16 (codec block size) width=842 is not a multiple of 16

Comment: @E.Abdel Thank you for the amount of assistance you have been giving to me, i will make a new test with the changes you suggest as soon as i have the time to do so.